# Is it legal to create a remote administration tool?

Tags: legal, keyloggers, remote-desktop

I'm planning to make a simple remote administration tool with the basic features that are available on all other rats in the market. However, I'm really worrying about legal issues after marketing it.

Is what I'm doing a legal thing ? If not, how can I make it legal ?

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Legal questions are highly subjective, and best suited for lawyers not admins. You should at a minimum include your location.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting legal advice, which not only may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction but also from case to case, and so should be obtained from a qualified legal practitioner in the appropriate jurisdiction rather than from the Internet where the well-meaning and logical opinions you receive on the matter may leave you more ill-advised than if you hadn't asked at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be certain about the legality of something, consult a lawyer.

That said, a "remote administration tool" as in a tool to permit system administrators to remotely manage computers under their control is legal in every jurisdiction I'm aware of.  On the other hand, a "remote administration tool" as in malware planted on somebody's computer to spy on them or take over their computer may fall afoul of various hacking, wiretapping, or other laws.  So the first thing to do is ask yourself which sort you're making.

Answer (score 2):

Most jurisdiction have laws against interfering with other peoples IT systems without their permission.

Some jurisdictions also have laws which forbid to create and/or distribute tools intended for breaking said laws.

Whether or not you are in such a jurisdiction and whether or not the tool you want to create conflicts with these laws is a question you should ask a lawyer who is familiar with the law in whatever place on this planet you reside.